# One of the module appears to be a part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

While trying to do an update from Tortoise svn, I am getting below error:

```
Command: Update  
Error: The path 'E:\MyProject\trunk\dev\OneofTheModule' appears to   
Error: be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater  
Error: working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this  
Error: working copy.  
Finished!:
```

When I checked svn version in cmd :

```
C:\>svn --version
svn, version 1.7.8-SlikSvn-1.7.8-X64 (SlikSvn/1.7.8) X64
   compiled Jan 11 2013, 16:31:23
```

From tortoise svn:

```
TortoiseSVN 1.6.16, Build 21511 - 64 Bit , 2011/06/01 19:00:35
Subversion 1.6.17, 
apr 1.3.12
apr-utils 1.3.12
neon 0.29.6
OpenSSL 1.0.0d 8 Feb 2011
zlib 1.2.5
```

Only one module has the issue ,(..\trunk\dev\OneofTheModule).What is the reason for this issue? What is the solution for this?

P.S: I have imported my project in eclipse luna and installed the Subclipse plugin.(I am not sure is this the issue). I guess, before that the update was working fine.But then I have uninstalled the same and still I cannot do an update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade both command-line Subversion client and TortoiseSVN to version 1.8 or 1.7 after ensuring what Subversion version your Subclipse plug-in supports. In other words, just make sure that all your clients use the same Subversion version and that's it.

Here is a brief summary: you have TortoiseSVN 1.6 client that does not understand newer Subversion 1.7 or 1.8 working copy format. The command-line client you have is Subversion 1.7. In Eclipse, you might have Subversion 1.7 or 1.8 version of Subclipse. Such mixture of client versions is discouraged and will lead to errors you've described.

See Apache Subversion FAQ at http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#broken-subclipse and SVNBook | `svn upgrade` reference at https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/upgrade/.

Comment: In that case we need to check out the entire stuff again right?

Comment: @tailorBird nope. Read the FAQ: http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#broken-subclipse

Comment: +1 for the link, it is really helpful. Let me upgrade it to a latest version. One question is, if the subclipse installation was the real problem, a fresh check out will work without any issue. Right?